# Flink SlidingEventTimeWindows doesnt work as expected

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, sliding-window

I have a stream execution configured as

```
object FlinkSlidingEventTimeExample extends App {
    case class Trx(timestamp:Long, id:String, trx:String, count:Int)
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI()
    val watermarkS1 = WatermarkStrategy
      .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[Trx](Duration.ofSeconds(15))
      .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[Trx] {
          override def extractTimestamp(element: Trx, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = element.timestamp
      })
    val s1 = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
      .flatMap(l => l.split(" "))
      .map(l => Trx(timestamp = l.split(",")(0).toLong, id = l.split(",")(1), trx = l.split(",")(2), count = 1))
      .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkS1)
      .keyBy(l => l.id)
      .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20),Time.seconds(5))) // Not working
      //.window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20),Time.seconds(5))) // Working
      .sum("count")
      .print
    env.execute("FlinkSlidingEventTimeExample")
}
```

I have already defined a watermark, but couldn't figure out why it is not producing anything. Does anyone has any ideas? My flink version is 1.14.0

My build.sbt is like below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.15"



libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % "1.14.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime-web" % "1.14.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % "1.14.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-queryable-state-runtime" % "1.14.0"
```

I am entering input data from socket(port:9999) like below:

```
1640375790000,1,trx1
1640375815000,1,trx2
1640375841000,1,trx3
1640375741000,1,trx4
```

tried to give larger timestamp than window size, but still not working.

Flink Web UI screenshot:
[web-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tewt.jpg)
[watermarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT7P4.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Earlier answer deleted; it was based on faulty assumptions about the setup.*

When event time windows fail to produce results it's always something to do with watermarking.

The timestamps in your input correspond to

```
December 24, 2021 19:56:30
December 24, 2021 19:56:55
December 24, 2021 19:57:21
December 24, 2021 19:55:41
```

so there's more than enough data to trigger the closure of several sliding windows. For example, trx2 has a large enough timestamp that it can generate a watermark large enough to close these windows that contain 19:56:30:

```
19:56:15 - 19:56:34.999
19:56:20 - 19:56:39.999
```

However, your execution graph looks something like this:

[image]

The problem is the rebalance between the socket source and the task that follows (the one doing flatmap -> map -> watermarks). Each of your four events is going to a different instance of the watermark strategy, *and some instances aren't receiving any events*. That's why there are no watermarks being generated.

What you want to do instead is to chain the input parsing and watermark generation to the source *at the same parallelism*, so that your execution graph looks like this instead:

[image]

This code will do that:

```
env
  .socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
  .map(l => {
    val input = l.split(",")
    Trx(timestamp = input(0).toLong, id = input(1), trx = input(2), count = 1)
  })
  .setParallelism(1)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkS1)
  .setParallelism(1)
  .keyBy(l => l.id)
  .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20), Time.seconds(5)))
  .sum("count")
  .print
```

In general it's not necessary to do watermarking at a parallelism of one, but it is necessary that every instance of the watermark generator either has enough events to work with, or is configured with `withIdleness`. (And if every instance is idle then you won't get any results either.)

Comment: I tried it, but not working really. I think I am missing another something about SlidingEventTimeWindows.

Comment: I've replaced my answer with the correct one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you really helped me understanding the flink internals on watermarks. It is working now indeed. I need to study more on relation between watermark strategies and parallelism levels. 
Sockets are very useful for solving a given problem on a small streaming dataset. After solving the problem, I will move on to the parallelization step.

I upvoted your solution, but my reputation doesnt allow me to increase it yet.